# INFORMATICA - Date format conversion

Tags: informatica

Hello guys i have a date format of 12/05/2015 i.e., dd/mm/yyyy . I need to convert this as 05/12/2015 i.e., mm/dd/yyyy . Can any one give me a solution .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Formats comparison in Informatica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828644/date-formats-comparison-in-informatica)

Answer (score 3):

Because function TO_DATE by default expects the date as a char value to be in the form 'MM/DD/YYYY', you need to specify you're handing it in as 'DD/MM/YYYY'.  Then you want the final output to be a string (presumably) in format 'MM/DD/YYYY', so for that you need the function TO_CHAR.  So you have to jump that hurdle, too.  The final statement for your example, then, looks like this:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('12/05/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

The output will be '05/12/2015'.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function TO_DATE

```
TO_DATE(Column_name, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: How do i convert yyyymmdd to dd/mm/yyyy . I am facing issues in this because i cannot find any format like dd/mm/yyyy .

Answer (score 0):

In informatica Help file, There is a chapter called "functions". In that check TO_DATE function.

TO_DATE( string [, format] )

String ---- Must be a string datatype. Passes the values that you want to convert to dates. You can enter any valid transformation expression.

format ---- Enter a valid TO_DATE format string. The format string must match the parts of the string argument. For example, if you pass the string '20150515', you must use the format string 'YYYYMMDD'.

Answer (score 0):

```
   v_PORT(DataType-DateTime)-TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(INPUTPORT),'DD/MM/YYYY')
   o_PORT(String)--TO_CHAR(v_PORT,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command, this will give you the value as per you requirement

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Column, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```