# Informatica -- How to convert 'DD-MMM-YY' to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: informatica

I am have one date (string) field in the format 'dd-mmm-yy' like '1-Jan-87'). Now I want to convert it as 'DD/MM/YYYY' like 01/01/1987).

Please help me in this conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INFORMATICA - Date format conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182784/informatica-date-format-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if the target datatype is DATE / DATETIME, then all you need is a DATE port in Informatica and you don't care about the format. (In fact there is no date format - it's a number)
So all you need is convert the input STRING to DATE with `TO_DATE(yourStringInputPort, 'DD-MMM-YY')`

Comment: Thank  You It Worked .. But it converting like 2069 2077 But i want 1969 1977

Comment: Well - you've got just two digits of a year. Informatica can just guess what are the missing two. Perhaps you could add them before converting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `TO_DATE`

```
TO_DATE(Column_name, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

OR

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('12/05/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Its not working .. 
Data type of source column is String & datetime of target

Comment: See the edit. Or there are other answers in the linked question?