# Date Formats comparison in Informatica

Tags: date, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have just started working on Informatica.
I have a column that is of string datatype which contains date. I need to check if the date is in the format **'YYYY-MM-DD'**. If so it needs to return 1 else if it is of any other format it needs to return zero.
I need to perform this operation in the Expression transformation.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function:

```
IIF(IS_DATE(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD'),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IS_DATE (input_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`